# Jupyter Notebook error while using PySpark Kernel: the code failed because of a fatal error: Error sending http request

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I and using jupyter notebook's PySpark kernel, I have successfully selected PySpark kernel but I keep getting the below error

> The code failed because of a fatal error:
>     Error sending http request and maximum retry encountered..
>   Some things to try:
>
> a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources for Jupyter to create a Spark context.
>
> b) Contact your Jupyter administrator to make sure the Spark magics library is configured correctly.
>
> c) Restart the kernel.

here's the log also

```
2019-10-10 13:37:43,741 DEBUG   SparkMagics Initialized spark magics.
2019-10-10 13:37:43,742 INFO    EventsHandler   InstanceId: 32a21583-6879-4ad5-88bf-e07af0b09387,EventName: notebookLoaded,Timestamp: 2019-10-10 10:37:43.742475
2019-10-10 13:37:43,744 DEBUG   python_jupyter_kernel   Loaded magics.
2019-10-10 13:37:43,744 DEBUG   python_jupyter_kernel   Changed language.
2019-10-10 13:37:44,356 DEBUG   python_jupyter_kernel   Registered auto viz.
2019-10-10 13:37:45,440 INFO    EventsHandler   InstanceId: 32a21583-6879-4ad5-88bf-e07af0b09387,EventName: notebookSessionCreationStart,Timestamp: 2019-10-10 10:37:45.440323,SessionGuid: d230b1f3-6bb1-4a66-bde1-7a73a14d7939,LivyKind: pyspark
2019-10-10 13:37:49,591 ERROR   ReliableHttpClient  Request to 'http://localhost:8998/sessions' failed with 'HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8998): Max retries exceeded with url: /sessions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000013184159808>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))'
2019-10-10 13:37:49,591 INFO    EventsHandler   InstanceId: 32a21583-6879-4ad5-88bf-e07af0b09387,EventName: notebookSessionCreationEnd,Timestamp: 2019-10-10 10:37:49.591650,SessionGuid: d230b1f3-6bb1-4a66-bde1-7a73a14d7939,LivyKind: pyspark,SessionId: -1,Status: not_started,Success: False,ExceptionType: HttpClientException,ExceptionMessage: Error sending http request and maximum retry encountered.
2019-10-10 13:37:49,591 ERROR   SparkMagics Error creating session: Error sending http request and maximum retry encountered.
```

note that I am trying to configure this on windows.
thanks alot

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue, you can solve it by not using a PySpark Kernel (notebook) but a Python 3 kernel (notebook). I used the following code to setup the Spark cluster:

```
import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# May take awhile locally
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
spark
```

Comment: wow, timely answer, this just fixed it for me. 

Is this a hack? *Should* we be able to use the PySpark kernel?

Comment: Good question, I quickly checked online, but I don't see a lot of other people facing the same issue. I think most people are just using the Python kernel.

Comment: That great answer, I wasted my 3 hours. Your answer saved my full day.

Comment: In my case, this solves the issue because it is not connecting to the cluster, just runs a local spark session, did you any config to some file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect your Jupyter Notebook to a Spark server through Livy (e.g. AWS Glue Development Endpoint), you have to replace "localhost" with the Spark server IP address in: ~/.sparkmagic/config.json

As mentioned here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/

Comment: Even after following the above link I am too getting the similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

Posting below answer as it may help someone facing this issue when using sagemaker notebook with Glue Dev Endpoint.

I received same error message in my PySpark kernel notebook. In my case issue was missing Lifecycle configuration attached to notebook instance which was somehow removed. I delete and recreate dev endpoint every day but it lifecycle config normally remains attached to notebook.